# GeoServer create UI for datastore to ask for configurations

Tags: geoserver, geotools

We are using Vertica for geospatial data analysis. We need to integrate Vertica database with GeoServer so that we can fetch and use Vertica's data in GeoServer.

How do I create an UI for the datastore (created using https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/datastore/index.html) where I can ask for username, password or other required fields for connection? (Just like the fields that are displayed when we add a new PostGIS connection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoServer creates the GUI automatically for you, provided the datastore:

- Is in the classpath
- It's properly registered in SPI (see `META-INF/services/DataStoreFactorySpi`)
- Declares the parameters it needs in the DataStoreFactory API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Andrea. I tried with the above approach but still, my datastore doesn't show up in the Vector Data Sources. Do we need any changes in the GeoServer code for this? I added the datastore jar and the driver jar but still no luck. Am I missing anything?

Comment: No changes to the GeoServer code are needed, if the store is properly implemented, and available in the GeoServer classpath (along with whatever dependency it needs).

Comment: Thanks Andrea Aime, I was finally able to do this.